# Load TensorFlow frozen model (as *.pb file), and keep training it

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm doing some work on Uber's Atari-model-zoo repository (https://github.com/uber-research/atari-model-zoo).

Basically, I'm trying to load a frozen model from an early stage of the training, and keep train it locally, while performing some actions on the graph (feedforward once in a while and so on).

Uber provides frozen models as *.pb files from different stages of the training, but I don't understand how to re-create the graph and load the weights and other meta-data parameters into it.

Ideally, I want to do something like:

1. m = import_model('.pb')
2. for epoch:

   2.1 for batch:

   ```
   2.1.1 sess.run(m.training_op, feed_dict={x,y})
   ```

thanks.